# Dynamic ng-bind inside a custom directive merging

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a button formed from my custom directive where once the user clicks it will go into `$scope.countClicker` in the controller where it will count the number of times the button has been clicked. The number of times it being clicked will associate the city name it will pass through to the Data factory. Then from the data from the Data factory it will create a panel as shown in directive.js

My problem is once I click more than once, all the expressions that SHOULD be unique turn to be the same. For example, $scope.name3 should only show "Osaka", but the previous 3 panels which all should have unique ID from my for loop ($scope.name0, $scope.name1, $scope.name2) all have "Osaka" as their title as well. I originally planned that the number of clicks could be used as an unique ID so each panel wouldn't clash with each other, but for some reason it is.

If anyone can please help point out why this is happening that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**directive.js**:

```
app.directive('addbuttonsbutton', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        template: "<md-button addbuttons ng-click='clickCounter()' class='md-fab md-mini'>+</md-button>"
    }
});  


//Directive for adding buttons on click that show an alert on click

 app.directive('addbuttons', function($compile) {
     return function(scope, element, attrs) {
         element.bind("click", function() {
             scope.count++;
             var counter = scope.count;
             console.log('this is scope count' + scope.count);
             angular.element(document.getElementById('space-for-buttons')).prepend($compile( //adding a panel to my view
                 "<div class= panel>" +
                 "<h3 id=title" + scope.count + ">{{name" + scope.count + "| uppercase}}</h3><br>" +
                 "<i ng-class=weatherClass id=icon></i>" +
                 "<h3 id= temp >{{fTemp" + scope.count + " | uppercase}}</h3>" +
                 "<p style= 'color: #FAFAFA;' >{{description" + scope.count + "| uppercase}}</p>" +
                 "<p>{{location}}</p><br>" +
                 "<div id= wrapper ><div id= first ><i id= smallIcons  class= 'wi wi-horizon-alt' ></i>" +
                 "<p id= eventID >SUNRISE</p><p id= subID >{{formattedSunrise" + scope.count + "}}</p></div>" +
                 "<div id= second ><i class=  'wi wi-strong-wind'  id= smallIcons ></i>" +
                 "<p id= eventID >WIND</p><p id= subID >{{speed" + scope.count + "}}</p></div>" +
                 "<div id= third ><i class=  'wi wi-humidity'  id= smallIcons ></i>" +
                 "<p id= eventID >HUMIDITY</p><p id= subID >{{humidity}}</p></div></div></div>")(scope));
         });
     };
 });
```

**Controller**:

```
var app = angular.module('weatherApp.controllers', []);


app.controller('weatherCtrl', ['$scope', 'Data',

        function($scope, Data) {
            $scope.count = -1;

            $scope.city = 'Berkeley';
            var cityCounting = 0;
            var counter = 0;

            var cities = [
          'Sydney, AU',
          'Melbourne, AU',
          'Tokyo',
          'Osaka',
          'Seoul',
          'Hong Kong',
          'London',
          'Amsterdam',
          'Berlin',
          'Paris',
          'Barcelona',
          'New York',
          'Dubai',
          'Antarctica'
        ];

            $scope.clickCounter = function(){
                cityCounting = counter++;
                $scope.city = cities[cityCounting];
                console.log($scope.city);
                console.log(cityCounting);
               Data.getApps($scope.city).then(function(data) {


             for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
                $scope.data = data;

                $scope['name' + i] = data.name;

                $scope['temp'+i] = data.main.temp;

                $scope['fTemp' + i ] = ($scope['temp' + i] * (9 / 5) - 459.67).toFixed(1) + " °F";
            }//end of for loop

            }); end of Data service
            }//end of controller
```

[image]

Comment: Are your console printing the values correctly on click of button?

Comment: Hi @Vivz yes, I'm printing out my clicks and they're correct

Comment: @Vivz I realized my error. It's the for loop. When I printed the for loop $scope.name[0-13] are all printing out, which explains why the panels are having the same expression. Do you have any suggestions in terms of entering the for loop and iterating once a click instead of having the for loop run 14 times all in one go?

Comment: You can use your cityCounting variable for assigning the data like this....$scope['name' + cityCounting ] = data.name;

Comment: Works like a charm :) Ty!

Comment: I have posted my comment as an answer. please upvote if it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove your for loop which is reassigning the same data to every variable by the help of your click count.

```
$scope['name' + cityCounting] = data.name;

$scope['temp'+cityCounting] = data.main.temp;

$scope['fTemp' + cityCounting] = ($scope['temp' + cityCounting] * (9 / 5) - 459.67).toFixed(1) + " °F";
```

Answer (score 2):

I realized my error was the for loop. In the for loop it was iterating 14 times and thus $scope.name[0-13] and all the other variables are firing per click, which is why all the panels were the same.

But with Vivz's help, I ditched the for loop and used my "cityCounter" variable instead.